# Using nested Any() method

Tags: c#

Suppose you wanna test or compare the equality of two Vectors.

Suppose you have:

```
string[] models = {"ModelOne", "ModelTwo", "ModeThree"};
```

And another one that you don't know for sure what will be inside of it, but you believe that it will contain the same elements like models owner above.

I have this method to make this verification and I use it in a Unit test passing the vector `models` presented above.

```
public bool TemplateForDependenciesTests (string[] v)
{
    var dependency = new Dependencies();
    var result = dependency.GetByReferencedModel(typeof(T).ToString());

    //foreach (var i in result)
    //{
        //if ((v.Any(model => model == i.ReferencingModelName)))
    //return false;
    //}

    return result.Any(x => (v.Any(model => model == x.ReferencingModelName)));
}
```

the result variable will hold the return of this method:

```
public IEnumerable<Dependency> GetByReferencedModel(string referencedModelName)
{
    return this.dependencies
        .Where(d => d.ReferencedModelName == referencedModelName);
}
```

The question is: How can I make that return statement in `TemplateForDependenciesTests()` work nicely and in a way I can snoop that indeed it is doing what I expect, because till now I moved some stones here and there, but it appears not doing what I want?

Comment: Are you just asking for a better way to check whether two lists contain the same values?

Comment: What do you expect it to do that it's not doing?

Comment: The Any() inside another Any(), that creepy problem, and all this question is about that single line. Just it!

Comment: The fastest way to get a good answer is to concisely state your goal. Telling us the nested Any doesn't work like you expect doesn't tell us what you think it *should* do, so any answers you get will be guesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're just trying to see if any member of `result` has a `ReferencingModelName` that's in the `models` collection. Seems like this would do it:

```
return result.Select(x => x.ReferencingModelName).Intersect(v).Any();
```

Now, if you want to snoop to see if it's really doing what you expect:

```
var intersection = result.Select(x => x.ReferencingModelName).Intersect(v).ToList();
// now you can examine the contents of the intersection list
// and you can return the result
return intersection.Any();
```

You might even go one step further:

```
var result = dependency.GetByReferencedModel(typeof(T).ToString()).ToList();
var names = result.Select(x => x.ReferencingModelName).ToList();
var intersection = names.Intersect(v).ToList();
return intersection.Any();
```

With that, you can examine the results of each step, and you should be able to see where the error exists.

Order doesn't matter to `Intersect`. That is if you have:

```
var x = new string["a", "b", "c"];
var y = new string["c", "b"];
var z = new string["b", "c"];
```

Then `x.Intersect(y) == y.Intersect(x) == x.Intersect(z) == y.Intersect(z)`, etc.

Comment: Yeah, you totally right! But "intersection.Any();" is returned as null. Would make difference if the order of the elements of both vectors are not compatible? Because actualy I don't know the order of the elements of "result".

Comment: @RodCosta: See my update. Also, you say `intersection.Any()` returns null? How? It returns a boolean. Or is `intersection` null? Or is it just empty?

Comment: Jim Mischel, Seems to when I'm converting "result" to ToList() passing to "intersection", intersection becomes "null", but while I'm hovering my mouse over "result" then I can see all its objects inside of itself, normaly. Strange. Something is happening when converting result to ToList(), then intersection becomes null.

Comment: @RodCosta: I suggest you expand your code as I showed. Then single-step each statement and examine the values after each step. Trying to examine the individual steps in `result.Select(whatever).Intersect(v).Any()` will be unproductive.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your lambdas easier to debug by making them multi-line statements. E.g. you could put breakpoints all over this to see exactly what's happening.

```
var resultList = result.ToList();
return resultList.Any(x =>
{
    bool outer = v.Any(model =>
    {
        bool inner = model == x.ReferencingModelName;
        return inner;
    });
    return outer;
});
```

I'll also note that with things like [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx) or [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx), and [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx), you could make all of these lookups much faster and more intuitively-coded.

Comment: You don't need to have statement lambdas to put breakpoints on the lines.  You can put breakpoints on expression lambdas.  Additionally, this isn't an answer, it's just a tip to aid in debugging to find the actual problem.

Comment: On the breakpoints: true, and good to note that, but it is easier to see what's going on, especially when you have multiple lambdas in one line, to break it out. The question seems to be mainly asking how to understand that line better, "How can I make that return ... work nicely and in a way I can snoop that indeed it is doing what I expect"

Comment: He also says, "it appears not doing what I want" indicating that it's not working, and he doesn't know why.

Comment: @TimS., that is a good way of doing it and I tried, but I faced some exact same things as in my example. i.e. The variables like outer, inner, x and model always appears as "Unknown identifier". That is hairy! Seems like nothing is passing in, just the name "ReferencingModelName" is recoginized, but idk...

Comment: Are you building this as Debug or Release? I don't see why you should see "Unknown identifier".